# Avoid character overflow in input field. How to mimic the input field behavior of Gmail? CSS only

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to implement same behavior as gmail auto input. The case is if in case amount of words overflows in input field it should line break.

As shown in Image:

My current behavior is: Text inside input overflows and its width remains constant.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried